# Is there a raw file size limit for android?

Tags: android

Can someone tell me if it is possible to put an archive file with a size greater than 1 mb  in res/raw  and at runtime copy it to sdcard and decompress it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. It will increase the size of your Application a lot but it is possible.

The problem is that until the program is started for the first time the user has to have the space on his device. 1megabyte is not that much but if the file gets bigger then 10 meg you should think about another solution.